# Database Reconnect After Failure

Tags: c#, .net, sql, debugging, try-catch

A program that I am currently working on collects and exports data to a SQL database. If there is a failure in the database, I have coded so that it will write the data to a CSV file. It is going to be an application that is always running with a config file that the user can change info (Such as Database connection) while the process is running. I'm having the problem of once I get into a loop of writing to a CSV file, I cannot get back to putting the data in a database until the application is restarted. Here is the relevant code:

```
class MethodClass
{
    public static void Method()
    {
        while (true)
        {            
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");

        //Normally Running Code that Generates the Data

        //Tries to write data to database 3 times                
        if (dbWrite != 2 && dbWrite != 3)
        {
             dbWrite = 0;
        }
        while (dbWrite < 2)
        {
             try
             {
                  db.TblData.InsertOnSubmit(newrecord);
                  db.SubmitChanges();
                  break;
             }
             catch
             {
                  dbWrite++;
             }
        }
        if (dbWrite == 2)
        {
             try
             {
                  db.TblData.InsertOnSubmit(newrecord);
                  db.SubmitChanges();
             }
             catch (Exception e)
             {
                  dbWrite++;
                  log.Warn("Database Write Error", e);
                  BackupMethod();
             }

        }
        if (dbWrite == 3)
        {
             try
             {
                  db.TblData.InsertOnSubmit(newrecord);
                  db.SubmitChanges();
                  dbWrite = 0;
             }
             catch
             {
                  BackupMethod();
                  log.Info("Still not writing to Database");
             } 
        }
    }
}

Class ConfigVariables
{
    public static string SqlUser = ConfigurationManager.appSettings["SqlUser"];
    //Other Config Variables
}
```

For reference, I just checked and the issue seems to be with getting the info from my Config file while the program is running. If I change other values in the config file, they have no effect until the next time that the program is run. Just so people know, I am editing the App.exe.config file in the Debug/Release folder.

UPDATE: It seems that if I assign the variable after `RefreshSection();`, that it will work. However, I put the variables in a separate class for a reason. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by creating a method in my ConfigVariables class that refreshed and reassigned the variables in a while loop on a separate thread. This allowed me to keep my variables organized in another class and not change anything with referencing them in the my code. Now I just have to do some performance testing; hopefully constantly doing this won't cause performance issues.